# Unable to add the js file dynamically

Tags: jquery

If a page is accessed from the mobile , i am trying to add a js file dynamically

This is my code

```
$(document).on('click', '.mybutton', function (e) {

    var ismobileornot = isMobile();

    if(ismobileornot)
    {
        $('head').append("<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova.js"></script>");
    }


});


function isMobile() {
 try {
    if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|pocket|psp|kindle|avantgo|blazer|midori|Tablet|Palm|maemo|plucker|phone|BlackBerry|symbian|IEMobile|mobile|ZuneWP7|Windows Phone|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
     return true;
    };
    return false;
 } catch(e){ console.log("Error in isMobile"); return false; }
}
```

But i am getting a error under browser console as

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kgm9o693/49/

could anybody please let me know how to resolve the issue .

Comment: `$('head').append('');` check here!!! you need to wrap it with single quotes.

Comment: Thanks , ya i did that but still the same issue

Comment: No that is not the same issue. checkout the network tab in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You are putting your `"` incorrectly. Try it:

```
$('head').append("<script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8' src='js/cordova.js'>\x3C/script>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to create the `script` tag as an object first with built-in commands and then append it

```
    if(ismobileornot)
    {
        var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
        script.src = 'js/cordova.js';
        $('head').append(script);
    }
```

Comment: @Jai, sometimes browsers don't respect the fact you've passed the element as a string. It is better to create it as an object and then append it.